# Apache nifi GetRethinkDB upstream connection invalid

Tags: rethinkdb, apache-nifi

I am trying to grab some data from my local rethinkdb using apache nifi with GetRethinDB processor. It shows me configuration error that upstream connection setting is invalid. Can somebody help me understand what it means and any ways to get over it? Is there another processor that i should use in conjunction with it?

Thanks

Neil

Answer (score 2):

Most "GetXYZ" processors are "source processors", meaning they are expected to generate data for the flow, and thus do not accept incoming connections (whose data must be generated upstream).

To alleviate this, the ListXYZ -> FetchXYZ pattern is used, here there are two separate processors, one (ListXYZ) is a source processor, which only gets information about the "XYZ" that are available. Then FetchXYZ accepts an incoming connection, and uses the information (usually in a flow file attribute) to actually get the XYZ resource. Using this pattern, you can replace ListXYZ with any other upstream flow/processor, in order to provide information about which resources to fetch to the FetchXYZ processor.

Having said all that, there are currently no ListRethinkDB -> FetchRethinkDB processors. If RethinkDB had a JDBC driver (which I don't believe it does, due to the nature of its data model and query model), you could use the "SQL" processors to fetch the data.

Long story short, I don't believe there is a workaround at the moment. Feel free to write a [New Feature Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/NIFI) for List/FetchRethinkDB or whatever, and especially feel free to implement them and contribute them back to the community! ;)